# Highlighting days on 720kb calendar

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I'm using AngularJS with 720kb datepicker ([Link](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker))

I wanted to know if it's possible to highlight certain days on the calendar (making `._720kb-datepicker-calendar-day` background: red for example). Like this:
[image]

I know you can set datepicker-class="" but this doesn't help much as this is not a class for individual days. Is there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the live demo of the lib, the easiest way would be to count days in javascript. It would be something like this:

```js
const calendarDays = document.querySelectorAll('._720kb-datepicker-calendar-day:not(._720kb-datepicker-disabled)');
const desiredDayOfMonth = 7;

calendarDays[desiredDayOfMonth-1].style.background = 'red';
```

[image: POC]

Maybe not the most elegant way, but it works.